# Forcing the cache of an imported CSS file?

Tags: css, caching, import

I have a css file that is called in my website called basic.css.

Within this file I have 2 imported css files from another server which contain large-ish Base64 encoded fonts.

(Before anyone asks it has to be like this... its all hooked up to a CP which uses CKEditor, so the CSS structure has to be like this in order to work everywhere)

Everything is working well except when navigating through the site it doesn't seem to be caching the imported css files and therefore the page load times are pretty bad.

The net is full of solutions to prevent caching but I can't seem to find anything on enforcing it! These imported files will genuinely never change so it's not a problem if they cache.. and it would surely make the site load faster (I'm no genius on caching though, so please excuse my ignorance).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not having your css cached is the downside to chaining your css files.

Comment: Ok, defeat accepted... I kept looking and whilst I couldn't find a solution, as you pointed out, I did find out you can assign multiple stylesheets to CKEditor now, so my problem is fixed! Thanks!